# pandas dataframe column creation based on existing column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i need actual_new column from actual in pandas dataframe.

```
start time      end time        actual      actual_new
4/1/2022 20:00  4/1/2022 21:00  0.749123    0.749123
4/1/2022 21:00  4/1/2022 22:00  0.749123    0.770175
4/1/2022 22:00  4/1/2022 23:00  0.749123    0.725439
4/1/2022 23:00  4/2/2022 0:00   0.749123    0.659649
4/2/2022 0:00   4/2/2022 1:00   0.749123    0.245614
4/2/2022 1:00   4/2/2022 2:00   0.749123    0.078947
4/1/2022 21:00  4/1/2022 22:00  0.770175    0.749123
4/1/2022 22:00  4/1/2022 23:00  0.770175    0.770175
4/1/2022 23:00  4/2/2022 0:00   0.770175    0.725439
4/2/2022 0:00   4/2/2022 1:00   0.770175    0.659649
4/2/2022 1:00   4/2/2022 2:00   0.770175    0.245614
4/2/2022 2:00   4/2/2022 3:00   0.770175    0.078947
4/1/2022 22:00  4/1/2022 23:00  0.725439    0.749123
4/1/2022 23:00  4/2/2022 0:00   0.725439    0.770175
4/2/2022 0:00   4/2/2022 1:00   0.725439    0.725439
4/2/2022 1:00   4/2/2022 2:00   0.725439    0.659649
4/2/2022 2:00   4/2/2022 3:00   0.725439    0.245614
4/2/2022 3:00   4/2/2022 4:00   0.725439    0.078947
4/1/2022 23:00  4/2/2022 0:00   0.659649    0.749123
4/2/2022 0:00   4/2/2022 1:00   0.659649    0.770175
4/2/2022 1:00   4/2/2022 2:00   0.659649    0.725439
4/2/2022 2:00   4/2/2022 3:00   0.659649    0.659649
4/2/2022 3:00   4/2/2022 4:00   0.659649    0.245614
4/2/2022 4:00   4/2/2022 5:00   0.659649    0.078947
4/2/2022 0:00   4/2/2022 1:00   0.245614    0.749123
4/2/2022 1:00   4/2/2022 2:00   0.245614    0.770175
4/2/2022 2:00   4/2/2022 3:00   0.245614    0.725439
4/2/2022 3:00   4/2/2022 4:00   0.245614    0.659649
4/2/2022 4:00   4/2/2022 5:00   0.245614    0.245614
4/2/2022 5:00   4/2/2022 6:00   0.245614    0.078947
4/2/2022 1:00   4/2/2022 2:00   0.078947    0.749123
4/2/2022 2:00   4/2/2022 3:00   0.078947    0.770175
4/2/2022 3:00   4/2/2022 4:00   0.078947    0.725439
4/2/2022 4:00   4/2/2022 5:00   0.078947    0.659649
4/2/2022 5:00   4/2/2022 6:00   0.078947    0.245614
4/2/2022 6:00   4/2/2022 7:00   0.078947    0.078947
```

Comment: Can you clarify how the two columns are related? E.g. how does `0.749123` in actual become `0.078947` in actual_new?

Comment: This data is after exploding the dataframe.In actual columns 6 unique values repeated 6 times but in new columns i want set of 6 unique values repeat rows wise on the interval of 6. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['actual_new'] = list(df['actual'].unique())*int(df.shape[0]/len(uniques))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
df['actual_new'] = df['actual']
```

or

```
df['actual_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['actual'], axis = 1)
```